# Swift crashes when creating a new CoreData Attribute to an existing entity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I'm trying to create a new **attribute** to an already existing **entity** programmatically in swift.
This is my code:

```
    let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
    var properties = Array<NSAttributeDescription>()
    let remoteURLAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
    remoteURLAttribute.name = "\(foundArray[indexPath.row]) id"
    remoteURLAttribute.attributeType = .stringAttributeType
    remoteURLAttribute.isOptional = false
    remoteURLAttribute.isIndexed = true
    properties.append(remoteURLAttribute)
    entity?.properties = properties
    model.entities = [entity!]
```

The App always crashes with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't modify an immutable
>   model.'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the data model **before you use it** to read or store data. It's mutable when you first load it, but it becomes immutable as soon as you use it for anything other than model edits.

Changing the model like this is usually a bad idea. But if it's necessary for some reason, you **must** do it before you load or save any data using the model.

Comment: You're right but I wanna to add a new attribute to an already existing entity. How can I do that?

Comment: The usual way is to [create a new version of the model file and do model migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html). It's possible to modify the model in code but **very** unusual to do so, and even then you still have to do model migration.

Comment: So which is the best choice: create a new model or find another way without creating a new attribute?

Comment: It's not a "new" model, it's a new version of the same model. Xcode and Core Data have built-in support for multiple versions of the same model file. That is the best and by far the most common way. In your case, create a new model version that adds this new attribute.

Comment: Can I follow this (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html) guide?

Comment: That link gives me a "not found" error, but the URL suggests it would be right if I could find it, since it mentions "creating a new version" of the model.

Comment: I created a new version of the main model but I didn't understood what to do now

Comment: Up above I linked to Apple's documentation on the steps; you want "lightweight migration" StackOverflow comments are not a good place to explain the process. Read up and ask another question if you have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Model is un-editable at runtime. See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel?language=objc), paragraph `Editing Models Programmatically`. You can only copy it and the make your changes.

Answer (score -1):

I have not actually tried this, but how about changing the model from a constant to a variable (i.e. var instead of let).